# What does Foo.Bar("id") = ID mean in Visual Basic Script

Tags: vb.net, vba, vbscript

I'm currently reading my client's API written in VBScript, and here is a statement which I cannot understand.

```
Foo.Bar("id") = ID
```

As it seems, `Bar` is a property of `Foo`, and `id` is somewhat passed into `Bar`, and I just cannot get it.

And, also, if applicable, how can I convert this statement into C# code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBScript (mis)use () to index into a collection. Other - more decent - languages use [] for this purpose.

So array access in VBScript looks like this:

```
>> arrX = Array(1,2,3)
>> WScript.Echo Join(arrX)
>> arrX(1) = "replaced"
>> WScript.Echo Join(arrX)
>>
1 2 3
1 replaced 3
```

In your case, Bar is a dictionary/hash that allows indexing by string:

```
>> Set dicX = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> dicX("key") = "Value"
>> WScript.Echo dicX("key")
>>
Value
```

A C# version would use []:

```
    Dictionary<string, string> dicX = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dicX["key"] = "value";
    Console.WriteLine(dicX["key"]);
```

I'm sorry I can't help you with Foo - you need to publish more info concerning this object.